# Kibana for ARM architecture

Tags: kibana

I can see that elastic is available as docker image for ARM.

https://hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8/elasticsearch/

But I do not see kibana for ARM. Is there any official or unofficial kibana version available that is compatible with elastic version 7.10.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use unofficial kibana version using the commands like this...

```
docker network create somenetwork

docker run -d --name elasticsearch --net somenetwork -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" arm64v8/elasticsearch:7.10.1

docker run -d --name kibana --net somenetwork -p 5601:5601   gagara/kibana-oss-arm64
```

This version does not includes "Machine Learning" feature.

```
# curl -u user:password -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://localhost:9200/_ml/inference/telco_churn" -d @telco_churn_model.json
```

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"current
> license is non-compliant for [ml]" }]}